# Pages return http 403 after application pool restart

Tags: 2010

We have very strange problem with our simple SharePoint 2010 site collection with several pages showing some data from external database. Those pages were deployed by `.wsp` package.

On application pool restart we experience `403 response` trying to show some of these pages.

Others (using the same datasource) work perfectly and service account has all privileges to database. Some of pages regarding sharepoint permissions (e.g. setting permission level at `.../_layouts/user.aspx`) also return `403` - but only for for some users.

For now we have developed a very strange (but working) "trick" or "routine" to fix it - we just need:

1. Go into "Site permissions"
2. Change ANY permission - e.g. change one group permission from read to read + full control.

This fixes the problem. We can then safely change permissions back to read for that group and the "faulty page" works anyway, until next app pool restart

Another strange thing - not everyone can change

Have you experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody could use this answer - the problem disappeared when we rebooted front-end server... :)